# Create a windows application using Microsoft Office Word add-in

Tags: c#, .net, memory, ms-word

I created a windows form application using the Microsoft Office Word add-in. The application has a huge process that consumes a lot of memory but the problem is that while the process is running, Microsoft Office Word crashes. Is there any solution for this? I think if we can separate the processes for the application instead of using the same memory of Microsoft Office Word, the process will not crash.

Please help me for this problem .

Comment: You mean you developed a VSTO Winform application for Word. It doesn't use the same memory as Word - Word is written in C++ and uses un-managed memory where as the VSTO winform app is managed code and is subject to GC. Here read this article about coding solutions that involve managed and unmanaged memory  http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto-com-interop  Why does word crash during the process? Is it an Out Of Memory exception? What is the error?

Comment: thanks Jeremy Thompson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void ReleaseObject(object obj)
       {
           try
           {
               System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
               obj = null;
           }
           catch (Exception)
           {
               obj = null;
           }
           finally
           {
               GC.Collect();
           }
       }
```